# Refreshing the Listview

Tags: android

Hi i have an app that contains 2 screens . The first screen(main screen) contains a ListView that is filling the rows dynamically by communicating a server. On clicking the row element a new screen is appears, there is a button on this screen, on pressing this button a communication with the server is made(for this i have used AsyncTask class). After the process is completed , i have to switch back to the first screen(main screen) automatically, and the previous row element whose process of communication with the server is just been finished has to be eliminated from the ListView. 
I am facing the problem regarding eliminating the row element of ListView. 
Please help!

Comment: use startActivityForResult to open second activity and use Custom adepter in list view and update the data of the adapter with new one and notify change to list..

Answer (score 0):

For `SimpleAdapter` use the `notifyDataSetChanged()` function.

Answer (score 0):

use `StartActivityForResult` to open second activity and use `Custom adepte`r in list view and update the data of the adapter with new one and n`otify change to list`.

http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/531998-android-startactivityforresult-and-finish-with-video-

Comment: notify did'nt worked.......on returning from the previous activity, i  again created the ListView....is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to start the second activity (when you click in your listview item) with  [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). So the second activity can perform the remove from the server and notify back to the main activity when the task is done. In your case, the main activity will receive the result from the second activity and will remove the item from the list view.
Hope that help!